Python: ThreadPoolExecutor or ProcessPoolExecutor out of memory
I have written an interface, which is mainly used to query data and return it to the front-end data file after processing. In the process of querying data, I use multiple threads, and processing data uses multiple processes.
My service is deployed on K8S, the amount of data requested by users is sometimes large (perhaps tens of thousands to millions), and the memory of the container often exceeds 10G after multiple requests. 10G is I add restrictions to a the container, container automatically restarts, but sometimes the following error message appears.
Concurrent future. Process.

**BrokenProcessPool**: a process in process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending. A process in process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.

I've tried gc.collect, chunking, and writing data to a file, as shown in the code below. How should I optimize to solve this problem？
@download_bp.route('/dataDownload', methods=['POST'])
@siwa.doc(body=GetChartDataBody, tags=['数据下载'], summary='数据下载')
def download_file(body: GetChartDataBody):
    file_path = get_chart_data2file(body)['data']

    @after_this_request
    def remove_file(response):
        try:
            os.remove(file_path)
        except Exception as error:
            logger.error("Error removing or closing downloaded file handle", error)
        return response

    return send_file(file_path, mimetype='application/csv')


import os
import gc
import time
from flask import request
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor
from functools import partial
from ..utils import get_login_user
from ..log import logger
from ..dtos.request_body import GetChartDataBody
from ..services.get_vars import conn_influxdb
import pandas as pd
from ..dtos.resp_result import RespResult
from ..exception import BizException
from ..settings import settings
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from ..services import pd_data_nan2none
from . import user_file_path
import pickle
import uuid
import shutil


def get_chart_data2file(body: GetChartDataBody):
  """
  多线程查询，多进程处理
  :param body:
  :return:
  """
  gc.collect()
  terminal_id = body.terminal_id
  vars_list = body.vars_list
  start_time_str = body.start_time
  end_time_str = body.end_time
  table_name = terminal_id + '_xcp'
  record_time_start = time.time()
  user_name = get_login_user(request)
  user_directory = os.path.join(user_file_path, f"{user_name}_{str(uuid.uuid4())}")
  os.makedirs(user_directory, exist_ok=True)
  result_df = gen_result_df(user_directory, table_name, vars_list, start_time_str, end_time_str, True)
  dtype_dict = {col: 'float32' for col in result_df.columns if col != 'timestamps'}
  dtype_dict['timestamps'] = result_df['timestamps'].dtype
  result_df = result_df.astype(dtype_dict)
  file_path = os.path.join(user_file_path, settings.FILE_NAME)
  result_df.to_csv(file_path, index=False, chunksize=10000)
  record_time_end = time.time()
  spend_time = record_time_end - record_time_start
  logger.info(f'{user_name} download all finished: terminal_id:{terminal_id}, query_vars:{vars_list}, query_time_range:{start_time_str}至{end_time_str},spend_time: {spend_time}s')
  del result_df
  gc.collect()
  return RespResult.success(file_path)


def gen_result_df(user_directory, table_name, vars_list, start_time_str, end_time_str, is_download=False):
  """
  生成处理完的df
  :param user_directory
  :param table_name:
  :param vars_list:
  :param start_time_str:
  :param end_time_str:
  :param is_download:   降频or 不降
  :return:
  """
  logger.info(f'start query and handle data：{time.time()} ')
  time_groups = gen_time_group(start_time_str, end_time_str)
  with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(partial(query_database, user_directory), vars_list, table_name, start_time, end_time) for start_time, end_time in time_groups]
    results = [future.result() for future in futures]
    del futures
    gc.collect()

  if not any(results):
    shutil.rmtree(user_directory)
    raise BizException(201, '该时间范围内无数据，请重新选择时间')

  file_paths = [os.path.join(user_directory, file) for file in os.listdir(user_directory)]

  with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    start = 0
    cnt = len(results)
    df_chunks = []
    while start < cnt:
      df_chunks.extend(executor.map(partial(handle_data, is_download=is_download), file_paths[start:start + 3]))
      start += 3
      gc.collect()

  result_df = pd.concat(df_chunks, ignore_index=True)
  result_df.sort_values(by='timestamps', ascending=True, inplace=True)
  shutil.rmtree(user_directory)
  del results, time_groups, df_chunks
  gc.collect()

  return result_df


def gen_time_group(start_time_str, end_time_str):
  """
  将时间分块，按时间多线程分块查询
  :param start_time_str:
  :param end_time_str:
  :return:
  """
  start_time = datetime.strptime(start_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  end_time = datetime.strptime(end_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  day = timedelta(days=0.5)
  time_ranges = []
  current_time = start_time
  while current_time < end_time:
    if current_time + day <= end_time:
      time_ranges.append([current_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), (current_time + day).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')])
    else:
      time_ranges.append([current_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), end_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')])
    current_time += day
  return time_ranges


def query_database(user_directory, vars_list_group, table_name, start_time, end_time):
  """
  查询数据
  :param user_directory
  :param vars_list_group
  :param table_name:
  :param start_time:
  :param end_time:
  :return:
  """
  query = f"SELECT {','.join(vars_list_group)} from \"{table_name}\" where time >= $start_time and time < $end_time"
  params = {
    "start_time": start_time,
    "end_time": end_time
  }
  client = conn_influxdb()
  result = client.query(query, bind_params=params)
  print(params)
  client.close()
  logger.info(f'finish query：{time.time()}')
  if result:
    file_name = os.path.join(user_directory, f"data_{start_time.split(' ')[0]}_{start_time.split(' ')[1][:2]}.pkl")
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
      pickle.dump(result, f)
    del result
    gc.collect()
    return 1
  else:
    return None


def handle_data(file_path, is_download):
  try:
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
      result = pickle.load(f)
    data_df = pd.DataFrame(list(result.get_points()))
    time_adjust = (pd.to_datetime(data_df['time']) - pd.Timedelta(hours=8)).astype('int64')
    if is_download:
      data_df['timestamps'] = time_adjust // 10 ** 9
      data_df.drop_duplicates(subset='timestamps', keep='last', inplace=True)
      data_df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
    else:
      data_df['timestamps'] = time_adjust // 10 ** 6

    data_df.drop(['time'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    data_df = data_df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').round(3)
    if not is_download:
      data_df = pd_data_nan2none(data_df)
    del result, time_adjust
    gc.collect()
    logger.info(f'finish handle：{time.time()}')
    return data_df
  except Exception as e:
    gc.collect()
    logger.error(f'handle_data function error: {str(e)}')



Chunking when you're writing the data to the file is kind of moot, because you still end up with a very large in-memory dataframe result_df.
One idea would be to write smaller, possibly unsorted chunks out to separate CSVs, then use the standard UNIX sort utility to merge chunks' lines into the final output file, so the full dataframe would never need to be in memory; sort itself tends to be pretty efficient (depending on implementation of course) to do this sort of thing, even more so if you use an ASCII locale.
Assuming your timestamps are lexicographically sortable (e.g. ISO8601 timestamps are), the general idea would be:
$ cat > a.csv
2024-01-01
2024-04-33
2022-02-55
$ cat > b.csv
2023-01-33
2022-01-11
$ sort a.csv b.csv
2022-01-11
2022-02-55
2023-01-33
2024-01-01
2024-04-33
$


I am really sorry that I forgot to mention that I have another interface that needs to use all the data result_df  for lttb downsampling. First, I will judge whether  result_df  volume reaches 80w. If it exceeds 80w, I will downsample all the variables and return the downsampled data to the front-end for drawing. So I need to know how many rows of  result_df  (how to calculate the amount of  result_df  without loading it into memory), and I need to know the sample ratio (if I'm working with multiple files, I need to know the amount of data in each file to calculate the ratio).

Okay, I'd probably then use an intermediate SQLite database (because it can happily be not-all-in-memory) instead of dataframes.
